# Trying to write junit test, missing some basics

Tags: java, junit

When I try to use assertNotLesser or assertNotGreater I get compile error .. and eclipse suggest me to create a new method called like this .. http://junit-addons.sourceforge.net/junitx/framework/ComparableAssert.html  I found it here I never used these options before but I need to write this test, I can do it jmock as well but I don't know how .. I need to compare my expected results let say 0, if the real result is greater that the test should fail.

Comment: Can you post the compile error?

Comment: `The method assertNotLesser(int, int) is undefined for the type..`

Comment: Check if you're passing the right number/type of parameters.

Comment: it doesn't appear at all when I push CTRL + SPACE in eclipse .. its not there

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add the JUnit-addons JAR to your classpath (download the archive here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/junit-addons/files/).

Alternatively, use `assertTrue()`:

```
asserTrue ("value1="+value1+" value2="+value2, value1.compareTo(value2) >= 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
assertNotLesser(new Integer(first), new Integer(second));
```

where first and second are the two integers you want to compare.